# Segmentation fault on sprintf in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, sockets, printf

This function is in a socket server. When the client sends a query, the server takes the query and finds matches from a linked list. The function works fine for the first few queries, and then a segmentation fault occurs. The problem occurs at the sprintf call(the one after "Before sprintf.\n"). I really don't understand why it works just for a few times. What have I done wrong?

```
char* searchNode(char* query) {
    int i, isFound, count = 0;
    node* temp = head;
    char* searchResult = calloc(1, sizeof(* searchResult));
    char* finalResult = calloc(1, sizeof(* finalResult));;

    printf("Before search node.\n");

    while(temp->next) {
        isFound = TRUE;
        temp = temp->next;
        for(i = 0; i < strlen(query); i++) { /* compare each char in both strings */
            if(tolower(query[i]) != tolower(temp->foodName[i])) {
                isFound = FALSE;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(isFound == TRUE) { /* if a match is found, write it into the temp string */
        printf("Match found.\n");
            searchResult = realloc(searchResult, strlen(searchResult) + 1 + strlen(nodeToString(temp)) + 1);
        printf("Before sprintf.\n");
            sprintf(searchResult, "%s%s", searchResult, nodeToString(temp));
            count++; /* count the number of results found */
        }
    }

    printf("Before finalise string.\n");

    if(count > 0) { /* if at least a result is found, add combine all results with a head line*/
        sprintf(finalResult, "%d food item(s) found.\n\n", count);
        strcat(finalResult, searchResult);
        free(searchResult);
        return finalResult;
    }

    /* if no match is found, return this message */
    return "No food item found.\nPlease check your spelling and try again.\n";
}
```

Comment: You are trying to print the string into itself. If you want to append one string to another, consider using `strcat` or `strncat`.

Comment: this line: node* temp = head; seems to be referencing a variable 'head' that is not defined.

Comment: this kind of line: char* searchResult = calloc(1, sizeof(* searchResult)); is unlikely to work because (in the beginning) searchResult is not pointed to anything in particular so asking for a dereferenced size is most likely to return 4, if anything useful

Comment: the (currently) int variable isFound is being set with either TRUE or FALSE.  However, it is not being initialized to either value and should be defined on a separate line as bool isFound = FALSE;

Comment: this line: sprintf(finalResult, "%d food item(s) found.\n\n", count); will result in undefined behaviour  because it does not point to an area long enough to contain the text being placed into it.

Comment: regarding this line: if(isFound == TRUE)  your code should NEVER compare against TRUE because TRUE can be anything.  much better to either: 1) if(isFound) or 2) if(isFound != FALSE)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to test the success of  `calloc`. And you are using it incorrectly: you need to allocate enough bytes for the 0-terminated string in it.

Notice that <strike>`char* searchResult = calloc(1, sizeof(* searchResult));`</strike> is deeply wrong: it is equivalent to `/* wrong code*/ char* searchResult= calloc(1,1);` and you cannot do that (you need to allocate a wide enough string); you've got some [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and you have the bad luck that it does not crash (SO contains a *lot of answers* about UB, see e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108)).

You should use [snprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html) (perhaps with [strdup(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html)) and you should take into account the result of `snprintf` + 1 for the terminating zero byte. You may want to use [asprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html) if your system provides it.

Please compile with all warnings and debug info `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. Use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and the `gdb` debugger.

Comment: it's amazing (in the bad sense) how people have no idea about the safe versions of stdlib functions and massively prefer the dangerous variations thereof...

Comment: I'd say the OP simply forgot(?) to realloc what `finalResult` shall finally be pointing to.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But why would it work for the first few calls and eventually crash? That really bothers me a lot. If it's not right, it shouldn't work at all. But why? I've been stuck with this for days. I still don't get it.

Comment: @KolyaH: you are wrong: UB is not right, but unfortunately, it may give the appearance to perhaps work sometimes. And UB sadly *does **not always** crash* ! (Cf some of my answers mentioning UB)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what that sprintf is going to do when passed searchResult as an argument. The man page on my system suggests that it is undefined:

> C99 and POSIX.1-2001 specify that the results are undefined if  a call
>   to  sprintf(), snprintf(), vsprintf(), or vsnprintf() would cause copying
>   to take place between objects that overlap  (e.g.,  if  the  target
>   string  array and one of the supplied input arguments refer to the same
>   buffer).

You should probably be using strcat there instead.

Answer (score 1):

just read the failing line

```
 sprintf(searchResult, "%s%s", searchResult, nodeToString(temp));
```

It says print searchResult and other stuff into searchResult. It cant possibly work

searchResult is not the Tardis

Answer (score 0):

You **are** adjusting what `searchResult` points to, but `finalResult` stays pointing to 1 `char` only, although it finally gets copied all the search result into, which most propably is more the 1 `char`, with this writing to invalid memory and provoking undefined behaviour.